# gdb addresses too short

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I'm trying to play around with ROP programming and therefore I am using gdb. So I am trying to follow this step:

```
(gdb) print not_called
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x8048444 <not_called>
```

but when I am running this command I get something like this:

```
(gdb) print not_called
$1 = {void ()} 0x40062d <not_called>
```

I am running this on a 64Bit machine:

```
dirk@discordia:~/devel$ uname -p
x86_64
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this correct that the addresses on my machine are two bytes less than in the tutorial? And if it's just a gdb switch or something that the addresses on my machine are displayed shorter. How can I switch the way the addresses are displayed?

Comment: Gdb doesn't print leading zeros.

Comment: And even if it did... `0x00000001` is the same as `0x1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running on a **64bit** system, which defaults programs to the **0x400000 page**, and the tutorial was built on a **32bit** system, which defaults to the **0x8048000 page**.

There is no issue.

(And if `gdb` didn't turn off **[ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)**, neither of those numbers would match, as the base page address would have been randomized '*for your protection*'.)

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the right address.

The output is only one byte 'short'. That is because the function is mapped at 0x0040062d. The leading zero byte is striped by gdb.